# Setting focus of ion-textarea with Angular's ElementRef: "Property 'setFocus' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'."

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created a textarea component that focuses itself when it's created in the ngAfterViewInit() method:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if(this.text.length===0){
    this.theinput.setFocus();
    }
  }
```

It works perfectly fine, the behavior matches exactly what I expected.

I'm using ElementRef to get the ion-textarea component:

```
@ViewChild('name') theinput: ElementRef;


<ion-textarea #name rows="1" ></ion-textarea>
```

However when running `ionic serve` and building the app, it doesn't build and shows an error:

```
"Property 'setFocus' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'."
```

at the `this.theinput.setFocus()` line of code.

If I comment out this line of code, build the app, and then uncomment - everything works as expected. However that is not a good solution.

Is there a better workaround for an issue like this? Extending ElementRef or something of that sort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

Use ViewChild decorator to get the dom element

```
@ViewChild('ref') ref:TextInput;
```

Then use nativeElement which is textarea in dom which include focus method on it.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if(this.text.length===0){
    this.ref['_native'].nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }
```

Example:https:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-hatcjc

Comment: Ok, this works. However - could you give a brief explanation of this solution? Is this not considered bad practice?

Comment: this is not a bad practice since we are using ViewChild Decorator to trigger nativeElement method

Comment: this.ref._native.nativeElement.focus();